# WKWebView Inside View and Inside ScrollView lost touch iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I used the following code for resize of height the WKWebView When the info is loaded completely

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {  
    var rect = webView.frame
    rect.size.height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    rect.size.width = self.webView.frame.width
    webView.frame = rect
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.webView.frame.width, self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height + self.screenHeigth - self.wkWebViewHeigth)}
```

My problem is after increasing the height of wkwebview, The view is not getting events in increased area. It only receives touch event below original height. The same way only can play any content video, image in the original height.

```
var webView: WKWebView!

@IBOutlet weak var viewWebView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

//MARK: - Lifecycle
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    self.webView = WKWebView()
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.webView.frame.size = self.viewWebView.frame.size

    if (webView != nil) {
        viewWebView.addSubview(webView)
        viewWebView.bringSubviewToFront(webView)
        webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        webView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

When added the WKWebView directly at the scrollView work! but when add the WKWebView to another view show me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I never found the error, but what I did was use a UITableCell for all content by solving the problem